# Program finishes unexpectedly

Tags: c++

All works well until it reaches the last else statement, but after that the program stops. How can I solve this?

```
for(int  i = 0; i<sizeVector; i++)
{
    if(i >= getIndex(inputs))
    {
        else if(inputs[i] == "Stanga"){
        draw(mergi);
        moveLeft(500);

    }
    else if(inputs[i]== "Jos"){
        draw(mergi);
        moveDown(500);

    }
    else if(inputs[i]== "Sus"){
        draw(mergi);
        moveUp(500);

    }
    else if(inputs[i] == "}"){

        break;
    }
    }
     else if(i<getIndex(inputs)){

        if(inputs[i].find("Procedura") != std::string::npos){

            std::string j = inputs[i];
            std::string y;
            for(int u =9; j[u] !='['; u++){
                y.push_back((char) j[u]);   
            }
            nume.push_back(y);
            i++;
            std::vector<std::string> com;
            for(int o = i; inputs[o] != "]"; o++){
                com.push_back(inputs[o]);
                i++;
            }
            comenzi.push_back(com);
            i++;
        }
    }   
}
```

getIndex() returns the index of "{". As I have checked, it works.

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with Qt, it does not use any Qt Class so you should not use that tag. You probably use it in your project but it doesn't mean you use it in all your SO questions. Or maybe you are confusing Qt Creator with Qt which are 2 different elements, the first is an IDE and the second a library.

Comment: If you want help then you must provide a [mre]

Comment: Typo?  There is no `if` to match with the `else if` *inside* the first `if` statement.

Comment: It is just written more on the right. I would have an error there.